# js убрать \n после цифр, не затрагивая само число

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, re

есть строка:

```
'\n\t\t\t\t14\n\t\t\t\t\n\n\n\n\nСоюз может  быть «душа в душу». Для ваших отношений важно соблюдать равноправие, когда каждый из партнеров одинаково проявляет ответственность и распределяются обязательства, находить компромиссы. В негативном проявлении партнер может притягиваться с алкогольной зависимостью, не воздержанный в эмоциях, проявляющий агрессию либо партнер может излишне подстраиваться с целью угодить. Конфликты в паре могут случаться из-за  грубости, алкогольной зависимости, привязанности  к внешним факторам (отсутствие статуса, денег и т.д.). В вашей паре важно придерживаться «золотой середины» во всем (в эмоциях, в еде, тратах),  уделять больше времени совместному времяпровождению, вместе духовно развиваться, посещать культурные места, практиковать йогу, медитации, очищение организма и др.\n\n\n\nРекомендации для создания гармоничных отношений:\n\n\n\nРазговоры «по душам»Совместное посещение культурных мероприятий (музеи, выставки, концерты, филармонии)Совместное творчествоУстраивать романтические вечера (прогулки по Набережной, катание на лодочках/катамаранах, провожать закат, ванна со свечами)Перейти на правильное питание вместе (моно вместе участвовать в марафонах по детоксу и правильному питанию)Совместные медитации\n\n\t\t\t\t'
```

мне нужно убрать все символы табуляции и все символы разрыва строки кроме одного после цифр вначале, как и \n в самом начале строки. табуляцию и разрывы строк вначале и конце я убрать могу с помощью:

```
    str.replaceAll('\t', '');
    str.replaceAll(/^\n+|\n+$/g, '');
```

но как убрать \n после и перед цифр?

я не силён в регулярках на js, да и в целом, но я пробовал так:

```
a.replaceAll(/(?:\d+)\n+/g, '');
```

это мне никак не помогло, т.к. убирает и цифры.

выход строки ожидается таким:

```
'14\nСоюз может  быть «душа в душу». Для ваших отношений важно соблюдать равноправие, когда каждый из партнеров одинаково проявляет ответственность и распределяются обязательства, находить компромиссы. В негативном проявлении партнер может притягиваться с алкогольной зависимостью, не воздержанный в эмоциях, проявляющий агрессию либо партнер может излишне подстраиваться с целью угодить. Конфликты в паре могут случаться из-за  грубости, алкогольной зависимости, привязанности  к внешним факторам (отсутствие статуса, денег и т.д.). В вашей паре важно придерживаться «золотой середины» во всем (в эмоциях, в еде, тратах),  уделять больше времени совместному времяпровождению, вместе духовно развиваться, посещать культурные места, практиковать йогу, медитации, очищение организма и др.\n\n\n\nРекомендации для создания гармоничных отношений:\n\n\n\nРазговоры «по душам»Совместное посещение культурных мероприятий (музеи, выставки, концерты, филармонии)Совместное творчествоУстраивать романтические вечера (прогулки по Набережной, катание на лодочках/катамаранах, провожать закат, ванна со свечами)Перейти на правильное питание вместе (моно вместе участвовать в марафонах по детоксу и правильному питанию)Совместные медитации'
```

учтите, что я буду перебирать множество похожих строк.

Comment: `учтите, что я буду перебирать множество похожих строк.` - если вы так пишете, то будьте добры предоставить хотя бы еще 1 пример входного и ожидаемого значения

Answer (score 1):

Возможно подойдет такой вариант:

```
const result = text
  .replaceAll('\t', '')
  .replace(/^\n/,"")
  .replace(/\n+/g,'\n')
  .replace(/([0-9]+)(?:\n+)/g,"$&")
```

- `replaceAll('\t', '')` убирает вообще все табуляции
- `replace(/^\n/,"")` убирает `\n` только в начале строки
- `replace(/\n+/g,'\n')` убирает повторы `\n` внутри текста
- `replace(/([0-9]+)(?:\n+)/g,"$&")` подставляет то что найдет - число и
  если есть `\n` после числа

первую и вторую регулярку можно объединить, например так:

`.replace(/^\n|\t/g,"")` - выше они расписаны для объяснения

Результат:

```
14
Союз может  быть «душа в душу». Для ваших отношений важно соблюдать равноправие, когда каждый из партнеров одинаково проявляет ответственность и распределяются обязательства, находить компромиссы. В негативном проявлении партнер может притягиваться с алкогольной зависимостью, не воздержанный в эмоциях, проявляющий агрессию либо партнер может излишне подстраиваться с целью угодить. Конфликты в паре могут случаться из-за  грубости, алкогольной зависимости, привязанности  к внешним факторам (отсутствие статуса, денег и т.д.). В вашей паре важно придерживаться «золотой середины» во всем (в эмоциях, в еде, тратах),  уделять больше времени совместному времяпровождению, вместе духовно развиваться, посещать культурные места, практиковать йогу, медитации, очищение организма и др.
Рекомендации для создания гармоничных отношений:
Разговоры «по душам»Совместное посещение культурных мероприятий (музеи, выставки, концерты, филармонии)Совместное творчествоУстраивать романтические вечера (прогулки по Набережной, катание на лодочках/катамаранах, провожать закат, ванна со свечами)Перейти на правильное питание вместе (моно вместе участвовать в марафонах по детоксу и правильному питанию)Совместные медитации
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let str = '\n\t\t\t\t14\n\t\t\t\t\n\n\n\n\nСоюз может  быть «душа в душу». Для ваших отношений важно соблюдать равноправие, когда каждый из партнеров одинаково проявляет ответственность и распределяются обязательства, находить компромиссы. В негативном проявлении партнер может притягиваться с алкогольной зависимостью, не воздержанный в эмоциях, проявляющий агрессию либо партнер может излишне подстраиваться с целью угодить. Конфликты в паре могут случаться из-за  грубости, алкогольной зависимости, привязанности  к внешним факторам (отсутствие статуса, денег и т.д.). В вашей паре важно придерживаться «золотой середины» во всем (в эмоциях, в еде, тратах),  уделять больше времени совместному времяпровождению, вместе духовно развиваться, посещать культурные места, практиковать йогу, медитации, очищение организма и др.\n\n\n\nРекомендации для создания гармоничных отношений:\n\n\n\nРазговоры «по душам»Совместное посещение культурных мероприятий (музеи, выставки, концерты, филармонии)Совместное творчествоУстраивать романтические вечера (прогулки по Набережной, катание на лодочках/катамаранах, провожать закат, ванна со свечами)Перейти на правильное питание вместе (моно вместе участвовать в марафонах по детоксу и правильному питанию)Совместные медитации\n\n\t\t\t\t';
let fixedStr = str.trim();

let num = fixedStr.match(/\d+/)[0];
let text = fixedStr.replace(num, '').trimStart();
let result = `${num}\n${text}`;
let expected = '14\nСоюз может  быть «душа в душу». Для ваших отношений важно соблюдать равноправие, когда каждый из партнеров одинаково проявляет ответственность и распределяются обязательства, находить компромиссы. В негативном проявлении партнер может притягиваться с алкогольной зависимостью, не воздержанный в эмоциях, проявляющий агрессию либо партнер может излишне подстраиваться с целью угодить. Конфликты в паре могут случаться из-за  грубости, алкогольной зависимости, привязанности  к внешним факторам (отсутствие статуса, денег и т.д.). В вашей паре важно придерживаться «золотой середины» во всем (в эмоциях, в еде, тратах),  уделять больше времени совместному времяпровождению, вместе духовно развиваться, посещать культурные места, практиковать йогу, медитации, очищение организма и др.\n\n\n\nРекомендации для создания гармоничных отношений:\n\n\n\nРазговоры «по душам»Совместное посещение культурных мероприятий (музеи, выставки, концерты, филармонии)Совместное творчествоУстраивать романтические вечера (прогулки по Набережной, катание на лодочках/катамаранах, провожать закат, ванна со свечами)Перейти на правильное питание вместе (моно вместе участвовать в марафонах по детоксу и правильному питанию)Совместные медитации';

console.log('Are equal?', result === expected);
```